# Python Linear Regression Error

Tags: python, csv, scipy, linear-regression, data-mining

I have two arrays with the following values:

```
>>> x = [24.0, 13.0, 12.0, 22.0, 21.0, 10.0, 9.0, 12.0, 7.0, 14.0, 18.0,
...      1.0, 18.0, 15.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 19.0, 13.0]

>>> y = [10.0, 9.0, 22.0, 7.0, 4.0, 7.0, 56.0, 5.0, 24.0, 25.0, 11.0, 2.0,
...      9.0, 1.0, 9.0, 12.0, 9.0, 4.0, 2.0]
```

I used the scipy library to calculate r-squared:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import polyfit
>>> p1 = polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

When I run the code below:

```
>>> yfit = p1[0] * x + p1[1]
>>> yfit
array([], dtype=float64)
```

The `yfit` array is empty. I don't understand why.

Comment: This is the value of ConnectionTimeHoursRounded + p1[1]: 
[ 44.23076923  33.23076923  32.23076923  42.23076923  41.23076923
  30.23076923  29.23076923  32.23076923  27.23076923  34.23076923
  38.23076923  21.23076923  38.23076923  35.23076923  33.23076923
  33.23076923  32.23076923  39.23076923  33.23076923]

Comment: When I use the following int arrays it still doesn't work: [24, 13, 12, 22, 21, 10, 9, 12, 7, 14, 18, 1, 18, 15, 13, 13, 12, 19, 13]
[10, 9, 22, 7, 4, 7, 56, 5, 24, 25, 11, 2, 9, 1, 9, 12, 9, 4, 2]

Comment: When I try to calculate r-squared I get this error: http://imgur.com/udtGCpI.  Sorry for posting a screen, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post this here.

Comment: See [ask] particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Okay thanks for your tips, can you please tell me what's wrong with my example? For everyone: please don't just downvote my answer without telling what's wrong..

Comment: Read all the tips. We can't reproduce your problem. Basically we're debugging for you but it becomes a chat and a conversation which isn't appropriate for the comments section. You tell a story with unnecessary details. It takes work to strip a problem down to its essence. Someone has to do the work, and the best person to do that is you.

Comment: Thank you for being specific! I editted my quesiton in a way so that I completely skip the CSV part (which is unrelevant and hard to reproduce). I also renamed the varriables in a more clear and content unspeciffic way. People should now be able to reproduce and learn from this problem.

Comment: Get rid of everything unrelated to `yfit = p1[0] * x+ p1[1]`. The plotting, the later questions. Just make it so we can reproduce that single result `print(yfit)`.

Comment: That's even better formulated, sorry for being so stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are performing [scalar addition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars) with an empty `list`.

The reason you have an empty `list` is because you try to perform scalar multiplication with a python list rather than with a [**`numpy.array`**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). The scalar is converted to an integer, `0`, and creates a zero length `list`.

We'll explore this below, but to fix it you just need your data in numpy arrays instead of in lists. Either create it originally, or convert the lists to arrays:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([24.0, 13.0, 12.0, 22.0, 21.0, 10.0, 9.0, 12.0, 7.0, 14.0,
...                  18.0, 1.0, 18.0, 15.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 19.0, 13.0]
```

An explanation of what was going on follows:

Let's unpack the expression `yfit = p1[0] * x + p1[1]`.

The component parts are:

```
>>> p1[0]
-0.58791208791208893
```

`p1[0]` isn't a float however, it's a `numpy` data type:

```
>>> type(p1[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

`x` is as given above.

```
>>> p1[1]
20.230769230769241
```

Similar to `p1[0]`, the type of `p1[1]` is also `numpy.float64`:

```
>>> type(p1[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Multiplying a list by a non-integer interpolates the number to be an integer, so `p1[0]` which is `-0.58791208791208893` becomes `0`:

```
>>> p1[0] * x
[]
```

as

```
>>> 0 * [1, 2, 3]
[]
```

Finally you are adding the empty list to `p[1]`, which is a `numpy.float64`.

This doesn't try to append the value to the empty list. It performs [scalar addition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars), i.e. it adds `20.230769230769241` to each entry in the list.

However, since the list is empty there is no effect, other than it returns an empty `numpy` `array` with the type `numpy.float64`:

```
>>> [] + p1[1]
array([], dtype=float64)
```

An example of a scalar addition having an effect:

```
>>> [10, 20, 30] + p1[1]
array([ 30.23076923,  40.23076923,  50.23076923])
```

Comment: Nice answer! But what is the fix? I assume defining `x = np.array([...])` and same with `y` will solve the problem, and be a clean solution?

Comment: @mart0903 I don't know what the expression `p1[0] * x + p1[1]` is meant to achieve so I don't know how to fix it. I have just explained why it's producing an empty array.

Comment: @mart0903 No, it won't fix it. The problem is multiplying an array by a decimal fraction which gets rounded down to zero. I don't know the meaning of it.

Comment: Ii seems like it does. Multiplying a decimal (or a numpy float in this case) with a numpy array is perfectly fine. The example works with numpy arrays :)

Comment: @mart0903 Ah, I see now. Yes. Thanks. I will improve the answer when I have a moment.